# No pre-fermentation gravity reading

Tags: cider, gravity-reading

I didn't take a gravity reading before my cider started to ferment. The recipe I followed said it would yield a ~9% cider, however I only put in about 85% of the sugar it specified.

Is there any way to get an accurate ABV reading after it's completed its fermentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a [vinometer](https://www.ibrew.com.au/pages/vinometer-instructions). They are meant to measure alcohol in e.g. wine.

Personally, I found vinometers rather finicky. When you use one, send your sample through a coffee filter or paper towel first. Tiny fruit pieces could clog it. That should also get rid of any co2.